# Trying to conditionally render different outputs based on the carts total cost in react.. i am stuck

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

ok i am updating this as i need additional clarification:

i have gotten my code to this point, it does not output correctly and i am unsure why. What i need this to accomplish. Take the basePrice of cart (which i already have from a container), checkFreeShippingStatus by seeing is basePrice is >= 75. if it is display freeShipping component else display paidShipping component -- the issue here is the code is not displaying out the actual div's.

additionally i need to be able to calculcate the difference from baseprice minus the freeThreshold- and display that if it is indeed greater than 0 as a variable inside of a div in the paid shipping component.

here is my code so far;

```
class CartPortal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      costTilFree:null,
      freeThreshold: 75,
      ShippingIsFree:'',
      ShippingIsNotFree:''
    };
    this.CheckFreeShippingStatus = this.CheckFreeShippingStatus.bind(this);
    this.costTilFree = this.costTilFree.bind(this);
  }


  CheckFreeShippingStatus = ({basePrice, freeThreshold}) => {
    basePrice >= freeThreshold ? <freeShipping /> : <paidShipping />
  }

  costTilFree = (basePrice, freeThreshold, CartContainer) => {
    this.setState({
      basePrice: response.data.basePrice
    },() => {
    this.setState({
      costTilFree: basePrice - freeThreshold
      });
    });
  }

  freeShipping = () => {
    <div className="box">
        <div className="shipment-box-free">
            <p className="shipping-cost">Awesome! You got <span>Free Shipping</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  }

  paidShipping = (cart) => {
    <div className="box">
        <div className="shipment-box">
            <p className="shipping-cost">Add <span id="amount">{costTilFree}</span> More for <span>Free Shipping</span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
}


  render() {
    return(
      <Subscribe to={[CartContainer]}>
      { cart =>(
      <div id="checkoutPortal">
         <div className="shipping-tracker">
        { this.CheckFreeShippingStatus(CartContainer) } 
        </div>
        { cart.state.items.length == 0 ?
           (
            <Grid container 
              justify="center"
              alignItems="center"
              spacing={0}>
              <Grid id="emptyCart" item xs={12}>
                  <h1>Your Shopping Bag is Empty</h1>
                  <a href={cart.state.homeURL} className="actionLink">Continue Shopping</a>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
           )
          :
          (
          <Grid container spacing={0}> 
            <Grid item xs={8}>
              <ProductList></ProductList>
            </Grid>
            <Grid className="orderSummaryContainer" item xs={4}>
              <OrderSummary></OrderSummary>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        )}

      </div>
      )}
      </Subscribe>
    )
  }
}

export default CartPortal;
```

Any help w/ examples are GREATLY appreciated!
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

So you define 3 different components:
`CostZero` `CostMoney` and `CostContainer`.
You define the presentational logic (styles, divs) at `CostZero` and `CostMoney`. Then at `CostContainer` `render` method you do:

```
render() {
return (
<div>
{this.props.cost > 0
  ? <CostMoney />
  : <CostZero />}
</div>
)
}
```

I kept the example as minimal as possible for you to understand the basics. It is fine to do calculations with *props* by defining *variables* in **render** method and then conditionally rendering using **ternary** **operators**. This is the react way of doing it. It is also fine using short circuits to render a component **OR** nothing. For example:

```
<div>
{hasTitle && <h4>{title}</h4>}
<p>Lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
```

The idea is to have the logic of what to render in a component, and the html and styles at other components. It is also a good practice to have only one component defined per file/module

Answer (score 0):

Of course your program might use different logic, but this example teaches you to simply render `<Shipping .../>` with all the necessary variables for *all* possible shipping situations. The Shipping module can contain all of the logic for determining how shipping is calculated, and based on what variables. The Shipping component can then intelligently decide which sub-component, `FreeShipping` or `PaidShipping` will be displayed.

```
const calculateShipping = (weight, address) =>
  { /* ... your functional code here ... */ }

const FreeShipping = () =>
  <div>Free</div>

const PaidShipping = ({ weight, address }) =>
  <div>{calculateShipping(weight, address)}</div>

const Shipping = ({ amount, freeThreshold, weight, address }) =>
  amount >= freeThreshold
    ? <FreeShipping />
    : <PaidShipping weight={weight} address={address} />
```

As a result of this choice, users of the Cart module do not need to be concerned with these intricate details. Since you're the programmer and likely the primary user of the Cart module, you receive these benefits too. When working with Cart-level code, you can now conveniently forget about all of the complexities of the Shipping module code and just focus on the Cart code.

Your `Cart` component should have state for `items` and a `shippingAddress` and you can implement methods (for example) `sumItems` and `calculateWeight`. Then to `render` the shipping section for our Cart -

```
class Cart extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) { ... }

  sumItems () { ... }

  calculateWeight () { ... }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
         // ...
         <Shipping amount={this.sumItems()}
                   freeThreshold={75}
                   weight={this.calculateWeight()}
                   address={this.state.shippingAddress} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

When `amount` is over the `freeThreshold`, such as `<Shipping amount=100 freeThreshold=75 .../>`, the `<FreeShipping />` component will be rendered, otherwise the `<PaidShipping .../>` component will be rendered.